# Can anyone help me diagnose issues with my rubber plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, leaves, ficus

I bought my rubber plant a couple months ago. I have it in a room that receives bright afternoon light - the window across the room is southwest-facing.

When I bought the plant it was quite full but has since lost most of its leaves. The top has good new growth but almost all the bottom leaves have dropped off. Since I took the below photo a week ago, all the leaves have fallen off the bottom limb.

[image: rubber plant]

The leaves have brown spots as shown here:

[image]
[image]

Could it be that it's not getting enough light? Could it be pests? I have only watered it twice since I got it so I highly doubt it's getting too much water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give it more water, let's say every week a little bit but let the surplus water get a way so no root rot will occur. I think watering twice in a couple of months is not enough. It is not a cactus. You can also give it some fertilizer. Furthermore, Ficus plants are known to shed it leaves after stress, this could be the moving of the plant from the store to your home.

However, the curled new leaves on top tells us that the plant is still experiencing stress. My guess is that it is not getting enough water, but it could also be temperature or other factors that were not mentioned in your question. The bright indirect light should be okay.

Comment: I'll try upping the watering schedule a little bit. Fingers crossed it'll start sprucing up.

Comment: Be careful for overwatering of course, good luck!